# Nonlinear heat equation $u_{t} = \Delta(u^{4})$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the nonlinear heat equation $u_{t} = \Delta(u^{4})$ in $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: |x| < 1\}$ with $u = 0$ on $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: |x| = 1\}$. The problem I am working on is to show that all solutions to this PDE tend to zero (pointwise) as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

The equation looks like the porous medium equation so I thought about looking at how the Barenblatt solution is derived, but the issue is that this doesn't cover all solutions, so I'm thinking that there is a general argument to prove the above result.

Answer (score 4):

Let $v = u^4$ and rewrite the PDE in terms of $v$ to get:
$$
v^{-3/4} v_t = \Delta v.
$$
Let $\;v = A(t) B(x,y,z)\;$ and separate variables to get:
$$
A' = 4 A^{7/4} c \quad \mbox{and} \quad B^{3/4} \Delta B = c \quad \mbox{for a constant } c .
$$
The DE in $A$ has the solution $\;A(t)^{3/4} = -\frac{4/3}{4 c t + k}\;$ for a constant $k$. So when $t$ goes to infinity $A$ goes to $0$ and therefore also $v$ and $u$.

Comment: You should format your answer using $\rm\LaTeX$. It's a bit hard to read as is.

Comment: You've done a good job on the separable solutions; I upvoted.  But what about (possible) non-seperable ones?  Cheers!

Comment: By the way, are you near Berkeley, Ca?  I know some people at Berkeley Chocolate . . .

Comment: @CameronWilliams: At your command :-)

Comment: Han de Bruijn. : Thanks for the formatting. I still haven't mastered latex. Robert Lewis: The non-separable case is the sum of the separable solutions. Since each term goes to 0, the sum goes to 0. Berkeley and Chocolate are the names of my dear departed dogs in the photo, and I live very nearby Berkeley in El Cerrito.

Comment: @berkeleychocolate: I'm curious why the non-separable case is the sum of separable solutions?

Comment: user187437 asked *the* question!

Comment: To user187437: I have no idea why and likely this is not even true since the DE is non-linear and so sums of solutions are not solutions. One needs a completely different argument for the non-separable case.